# How do I force a CVC check in the Stripe API?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, payment

Reading the documentation, I saw that I need to create a customer if I want to check a card's info without having to charge it. But the CVC/CVV verification process always returns:

> cvc_verification : unavailable

How can I force this process ?

```js
const costumer = sk_stripe.customers.create({
  source : result.id, //this is the token
  email : "email@gmail.com",
  cvc_verification : true // something like this maybe?
})
```

By the way, I'm using live keys.

Comment: also second issue, i noticed stripe is even adding totally fake cards to customers, im guessing this 0$ auth thing isnt safe, how do i turn it into a 1$ auth? thanks